# Trigger Custom Event From Iframe To Parent Document

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I am having some trouble to fire a custom event inside an iframe and detect it from the parent document.
Both iframe and parent document have the same origin (same protocol, same host, same port).

Any advises?

Comment: Please write more clearly of what's `the same source`.

Comment: you can call parent.functionname() from your iframe.

Comment: same protocol, same host, same port

Comment: what if parent window is in different domain, then cannot raise events on parent window from child iframes.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This works:

```
parent.$('body').trigger('eventName');
```

the event triggered inside the iframe will be detected in the parent document.

Comment: What if the parent page doesn't include jQuery?

Comment: You can use ```window.addEventListener``` as suggested below.

Answer (score 53):

I ran into a similar problem and used `window.postMessage` to solve.

Currently, the API only supports passing a string, but if you modify your solution it can be powerful.  More details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage)

From the source page (being consumed by an iframe): 
postMessage API expects 2 params - message , target

ex: `window.parent.postMessage("HELLO_PARENT", 'http://parent.com');`

From the parent page (contains iframe. Eg Container):

1. Add an event listener as you normally would

   ```
    window.addEventListener('message', handleMessage, false);
   ```
2. Define your function with event.origin check (for security) \

   ```
    function handleMessage(event) {  
        if (event.origin != "http://child.com") { return; }  
        switch(event.data) {   
             case "HELLO_PARENT":  
                alert("Hello Child");  
                break;  
        } 
    }
   ```

Comment: I had troubles passing objects in every IE and Edge

Comment: @FarzadYZ - Your comment appears to contradict [what MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage): "The `window.postMessage()` method safely enables cross-origin communication."

Comment: JSON.stringify(yourObject) to send it via postMessage

Comment: I need to do the same but the domain of the inner frame is different that the parent document. How I can achiever this?

Answer (score 44):

A consistent answer supporting both same-domain and cross-domain iframes is to use event system.

The goal is to send a custom event from iframe to parent.

In the iframe source file:

```
var myCustomData = { foo: 'bar' }
var event = new CustomEvent('myEvent', { detail: myCustomData })
window.parent.document.dispatchEvent(event)
```

And add this in the parent file which contains the iframe:

```
window.document.addEventListener('myEvent', handleEvent, false)
function handleEvent(e) {
  console.log(e.detail) // outputs: {foo: 'bar'}
}
```

Comment: Can I check how does this work for cross-domain iframe?  `window.parent.document` throws CORS error (in case of cross domain iframe).

Comment: It didn't work for me. I'm in an angular 6 environment. Perhaps there is something that blocks this communication, not sure.

Answer (score 2):

I have also find my way to solve this problem with jquery:

in parent file:

```
<body>
        <iframe src="something.html"></iframe>

</body>

<script>
 window.document.addEventListener('event', function(e){
            console.log("event:" + e.detail);
            $("iframe").contents().find(".class[title='" + e.detail + "']").css(someChanges);
</script>
```

so you **don't need to add any other** EventListener **in your iFrames**.

of course maybe you want see my CustomEvent:

```
var test  = "1";
var event = new CustomEvent('event', { detail: test })
                window.document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

I hope I could help somebody...