# jquery event delegation with iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a page that has image thumbnails for videos.  When a visitor clicks on a thumbnail, I have an overlay that is dynamically created, that plays the video.  The overlay is a div that has an iframe in it that has the html tag for the video (html5 video tag).  ***This iframed content is hosted on the same site, so there is no cross-domain issues***.

What I'm looking to do is use jQuery to hook video events to the video.  The code for this is on the parent page.  So here's the thing.  After the video is loaded, I can put this into the console, and it works just fine:

```
$('body iframe[src*="VideoOverlay"]').contents().find('video').on('timeupdate',function(){console.log('Time: ',this.currentTime);})
```

However, what I really need to do is translate this into something that works to be a delegated event *before* the iframe exists.

I've tried various things such as

```
// attempt #1
$('body').on('timeupdate',function(){console.log('Time: ',this.currentTime);});

// attempt #2
$('body').on('timeupdate','iframe[src*="VideoOverlay"]',function(){console.log('Time: ',this.currentTime);})
```

.. and a couple other minor variations, but it doesn't work.  My guess here is that events don't bubble up from a child window to parent window, which makes sense for cross-domain windows, but I thought maybe it would if it's same domain, but it doesn't (?).

So.. near as I thought next best thing would be to do some kind of "iframe has been added" delegated event, then use `.contents()...` but near as I can tell, this is a mutation (?) event and support for it is a bit shady.

So.. near as I can tell, the next best thing is to check for existence of the iframe and wrap that in a `setInterval` but I don't really like this solution because a) things like this have performance considerations, b) I will need to account for that it's not perfectly timed, vs. the video events.  For example I need to hook into video play (videos are autoplayed) and I might miss that event, and a certain amount of milliseconds (whatever my interval is), etc.. IOW it makes for some ugly coding..

So.. I'm kind of hoping maybe I'm missing something as far as delegated events in iframes in the first place, or if my `setTimeout` solution really is the lesser evil at this time.. thoughts?

**Edit More info:**

I know there are things like youtube API and other video frameworks out there with APIs that deal with this stuff.  This is not youtube vieos or some other API. It is straight .mp4 videos hosted on my own site, same domain as parent page, using regular html5 video tags. The caveat is that it is included as a separate iframe content.

I do not have control / ability to change this setup (red tape).

I (maybe - again, red tape) *do* have ability to put the event handler code into the iframe content itself, which would solve for my problem, but introduce other problems.  The ultimate goal here is to trigger google analytics tracking for tracking video interaction. The google analytics library is on the parent page.  I know I can do things like `window.parent` but this also complicates things, and this also is a solution I'd like to avoid because each video has its own file for the iframe so I would have to make changes to all present and future video files which I'd like to avoid..

Comment: `before the iframe exists`. You can't because it creates a new window. Can use load event of iframe to do your event binding

Comment: also postMessage API would be good for what you want

Answer (score -1):

You can specifically trigger an event in the parent from within the iframe.

```
parent.$('body').trigger('eventName');
```

Credit to here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12967903/1905055