# How to trigger an event from iframe content to outer website?

Tags: javascript, angular, iframe, iframe-app

I am working on chat-bot which is intended to work with all domains. suppose i have a chat-bot side under 'chat.mybot.com'(iframe)(done on angular) and my website is 'example.com', here i cant listen to events of 'chat.mybot.com'(iframe) from 'example.com' because its on different domains.

### Solution if it was on same domain

```
$('iframe#chat_bot').load(function(){
  $(this).contents().find("body").on('click','#showthat',function(event){ 
    alert("div with id 'showthat' clicked inside iframe"); 
  });
});
```

### Problem

How to i do it in case of cross domain situation?

I have researched a bit and took a look at other chat apps but still cant get a clear idea how to do it.

Any suggestions or thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: I think iframes are supposed to be independent and isolated, especially in a cross-domain situation. You probably can't trigger events cross-frame.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trigger Custom Event From Iframe To Parent Document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12967616/trigger-custom-event-from-iframe-to-parent-document)

Comment: @PalKerecsenyi :
i don't it's the duplicate question if you check "(same protocol, same host, same port)." in other question, you would understand.. i am looking for different domain solution.. which i clearly mentioned in question.. i can solve it if it were on same domain with the code i have shown in question.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.

```
parent.$('body').trigger('eventName');
```

The event triggered inside the iframe will be detected in the parent document.

OR

```
$('#InnerIframe').contents().find('#SuperWebF1').trigger( "click" );

InnerIframe - ID of IFrame
SuperWebF1 - ID of the button
```